# How to reload page with hash url using Laravel form select

Tags: laravel

I'm working on a laravel project and I notice a statement like this in a blade file:

```
{{ Form::select('chapter', $chapters, $chapter_id) }}
```

I see a drop down when I visit the page in my browser.  The moment I change the drop down, the page refreshes and I see `?chapter=<some value>` query string in my browser.  My guess is that the `<select>` onchange event triggers a form submission, which is default Laravel behaviour

I want to change the behaviour such that form submission/page reload will create the following query string/url components : `?chapter=<some value>#searchresults`.  What's the Laravel approach to include the `#searchresults` hash phrase as part of the form submission / page reload?

Comment: Can you provide reproduction? "it is a default laravel behaviour" - no it is not, Form is not even a Laravel part for a couple of years now. You are using some old version or LaravelCollective/html

Comment: @chojnicki you are correct, I mis-diagnosed the problem.  I'll continue debugging to find the real issue.